# Why do i get a FileLoadException when calling CreateInstanceFrom after assigning a custom permission to an AppDomain?

Tags: c#, appdomain, fileloadexception

I try to build an application with different AppDomains and permissions.
The starting application creates a new AppDomain B and uses **CreateInstanceFrom** to instantiate a class from a different dll.
I can also assign different (standard) permissions to the permission set i use to create the AppDomain.
So far, this works fine.

No i create a **custom permission** (in a different dll as mentioned in [Implementing a Custom Permission](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yaah0wb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and try to add this permission to my permission set.
Instantiating and assigning the permisson works, but when i call CreateInstanceFrom, a FileLoadException (HRESULT: 0x80131016) is thrown.
I don't know why this exception is thrown...
Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: That's a very odd error code, a problem with the "file load level".  Which tracks the stages of loading an assembly in the CLR.  I seriously doubt you can get help with this when you don't post repro code.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but i will answer anyway for anyone who might stumble upon this issue in the future.

You need to do all of these things:

1. Make sure that your assembly has strong name (Add the AssemblyKeyFile attribute with a valid keyfile to your assembly).

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("YouKeyFile.snk")]
```

2. Run the assembly that defines your custom permissions in full trust (Add the assembly to the fullTrustAssemblies argument of the AppDomain.CreateDomain method). Assembies that define code access permissions must run in full trust, as mentioned in microsoft documentation for [CodeAccessPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.codeaccesspermission?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

```cs
// Example of retrieving the StrongName from a loaded assembly
var name = assembly.GetName();
var strongName = new StrongName(new StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(name.GetPublicKey()), name.Name, name.Version);

// The full trust assemblies go at the end of the argument list, after everything else
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandbox", null, yourADSetup, yourPermSet, strongName);
```

3. Add the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute to your assembly.

```cs
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```